# Magento 2.3: Overwrite minicart content.html

Tags: magento2.3, mini-cart

I wanted to do some minor changes to the minicart in Magento 2.3. So I copied

`/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html`

to

`/app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html`

and it didn't work. I cleared the file and just added "blah". I then cleared the caches, the indexes, ran `setup:upgrade` and `setup:static-content:deploy -f`. Deleted `var/page_cache/*` and `pub/static/`. No changes

So I left it because I had enough other things to do, and now, a week later, I see that the minicart only displays "blah".

So I changed the files content to what they needed to be, but now it won't pick up any changes again. I've read all topics on this regard, but no solution yet. What am I missing?!

Comment: You have to delete content.html file from =>pub/static/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart` and reload page again.

Changes are applied.

Comment: Yeah you'd think so. But as I wrote I (also) deleted the complete pub/static/* folder, including those files, and those files specifically; still no changes..

Comment: have to deploy static file using command => php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: I did, still no changes...

Comment: C'mon, I'm no idiot ;) I did that.